# Need to know if this lambda can be converted to LINQ syntax and how

Tags: c#, linq

This is just a research question. But is is possible to convert the lambda exp to query syntax and how to do it

```
dbContext.Items.GroupBy(x => x.MobileNo)
                      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedDate).First());
```

Query syntax sample:

```
// The below one does not work as expected
    from x in dbContext.Items
    group x by x.MobileNo into groupedResult
    select groupedResult;
```

Comment: Please clarify what you were expecting to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: The proper name is **query syntax** (your second version) as opposed to **method syntax** (your first version). There is no such thing as "old syntax".

Comment: @Equalsk - What i want - I want to group items by mobile number and get the one with most recent date from grouped result. The lambda expression works as expected. I just want to know how to do this using query syntax.

Comment: Methods like `First` that return a single element cannot be converted into query syntax so you cannot get completely rid of the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix [query- and method syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx):

```
var query = from item in dbContext.Items
            orderby item.CreatedDate descending  
            group item by item.MobileNo into numberGroup
            select numberGroup.First();
```

Not all LINQ methods are supported in query-syntax which is translated to method calls.

Comment: @Default: you're right, the old vb.net query returned only one item. I've edited it.

Comment: hm.. why post the vb.net version? It's not requested and the question is tagged C#, not .NET. Not saying it's wrong, just wondering why

Comment: @Default: doesn't make any sense anymore because C# and VB.NET are now equal